# Regular Expression RegEx for no special characters and atleast one letter

Tags: php, regex, expression

I am trying to create a regular expression that does not allow any special characters, but also requires at least one letter (alphabet) to pass. The alphabet can be capital or lowercase.

Example required pass and fail cases

- Hello World - PASS
- HELlO WoRLD - PASS
- HELLOWORLD! - FAIL
- HELLO123 World - PASS
- 12345 - FAIL

I would also like to allow -, and _ characters.

This is what I have created so far: `^(?=.*[A-Z]).{3,25}$`

The above RegEx checks to make sure that an alphabet exists within the expression, but I would also like to disallow special characters.

Can someone explain how I can add the extra check within the same regular expression?

Comment: What exactly makes a character special for your use case?

Comment: I meant anything other than alphanumeric, with the exception of - and _, in this case. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont' want to allow `-` or spaces at the start or at the end, you could use 2 lookahead assertions, 1 for the number of characters and the other one to assert a char A-Z.

```
^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=.{3,25}$)\w+(?:[\h-]\w+)*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])` Assert an uppercase char A-Z
- `(?=.{3,25}$)` Assert 3 - 25 chars
- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `(?:[\h-]\w+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching either a horizontal whitespace char or `-`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nEszz0/1)

Answer (score 0):

Change the `.` to be your allowed character list. Something like:

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])[\w\h-]{3,25}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/j4wuUP/2/

```
[\w\h-]
```

(`\w`) allows for `a-zA-Z0-9_`, (`\h`) horizontal whitespace, and `-`s. The `-` must be first, last, or escaped; otherwise it will create a range of ascii characters. In non-PCRE flavors escaping is not possible so it must be first or last.

Comment: Thank you, this is spot on! Amazing example.

Comment: Great, if this resolves your issue please remember to accept it.